# Under what circumstances (other than defamation) is "truth an absolute defense" against prosecution?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, defense

My understanding is that "truth is an absolute defense" against a "defamation" charge, in the U.S. (Although you could be charged with something else such as "publication of private facts.")

If you shouted "fire" in a crowded theater, and there really was a fire, would "truth be an absolute defense"? If so, under what heading would this doctrine fall, since we are not dealing with "defamation"?

On the other hand, "truth is NOT an absolute defense" against "defamation" in the United Kingdom. (At least as I learned UK law in the 1990s.) Are there any other instances in the UK where "truth is not an absolute defense"?

Comment: I think the issue is that one of the elements of defamation is that the statement be *false*.  So therefore this applies to any other crime or tort which has a similar element.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I believe that what you said about "defamation" is true in the U.S. But not in the U.K. where truth is not an absolute defense.

Comment: Why would someone need a defence if "*there really was a fire*"? Should it read "*there really was **not** a fire*"?

Comment: @RockApe: The issue in the question is that "truth is an absolute defense" in the US, e.g. against defamation, but not in the UK. Therefore, it is unwise to "trivialize" the "absoluteness" of the defense, because it does not apply in all times and places (even in the English-speaking world).

Comment: What does "yelling fire in a crowded theater" have to do with defamation? Maybe if you say "John yelled fire in a crowded theater" in an attempt to defame somebody.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I was trying to explore the commonalities (or differences as the case may be) between "truth is an absolute defense" in the case of defamation, and in the case of "yelling fire." One (common) concept applied to two (vastly) different locales.

Comment: Truth is an absolute defense to almost any fraud charge (assuming it is not just "technically true" but implies something false).

Comment: @Ron Beyer "yelling fire in a crowded theater" is a case where false speech is (or may be) criminal, but true speech is not, indeed is praiseworthy. In a defamation case false speech is a tort, true speech is not.

Comment: In E&W "truth" is a statutory defence under [s.2(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2013/26/crossheading/defences?timeline=false) of the Defamation Act 2013: "*It is a defence to an action for defamation for the defendant to show that the imputation conveyed by the statement complained of is substantially true.*"

Comment: So maybe I'm not clear on what "absolute" means here, and in what sense that's different between US and UK.  From @RockApe's quote, it seems that in either, if the defendant can prove the truth of the claim, they cannot be found liable for defamation.  I believe, though, that there are differences in who has the burden of proof, what the standard of proof is, and how "truth" is interpreted.

Comment: @NateEldredge: In the UK, it is also possible to be successfully sued for defamation if you "broadcast" inconvenient truths, such as "Jane Doe was born out of wedlock."  That is to say that "truth" is not as "absolute" a defense in the UK as it is in the US. Put another way, under UK law, if Jane Doe's mother was married to Mr. Doe at the time of her birth, that would be defamatory even if DNA tests prove that Mr. Doe was not her biological father.

Comment: @Libra: What you're saying seems to contradict the statute cited by Rock Ape.  Are you saying that courts interpret the statute in an unusual way, or what?  Can you cite examples?  Or are you talking about the situation prior to 2013?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I may be "outdated." I was quoting UK law as I learned it in the 1990s (and I added that parenthetical to my question). I am fuzzy on the details, but apparently the "McLibel" case had a few repercussions.

Comment: What if I inform all of Joe's neighbours that Joe had been arrested for murder - when I fully know that he was completely exonerated and the real murderer is in jail right now. It's literally the truth, but completely misleading.

Comment: @gnasher729: I don't think this is a case where the principle of "truth as an absolute defense" is violated. I think it's more like the case cited in User 6726's answer about  "Initiating or circulating a report or warning of an alleged or impending fire, explosion, crime, or other catastrophe, knowing that such report or warning is false" That is, even though the statement is literally true, the "warning" implied by telling about Joe's being arrested for murder is false. If so, that would be an important, non trivial distinction. See also ohwillke's comment above.

Comment: @gnasher729 I added a paragraph in reposne to your comment to my answer. It is the implied statements that are false and so defamatory in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The original phrase ["falsely shouting fire in a theatre and causing a panic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shouting_fire_in_a_crowded_theater) came from the opnion by Justice Holmes in [*Schenck v. United States*, 249 U.S. 47 (1919)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schenck_v._United_States) where it was a **metaphor** for speech that might validly be prohibited under he First Amendment. It served to introduce the famous "Clear and present danger" test. The issue in that case was whether  distributing fliers urging people not to submit to the draft could be the reason for a conviction under the Espionage Act, or whether such action was protected by the First Amendment. Holmes held it was not protected. The case was not about any actual shout of "fire".

The Court has generally held that true speech may not be prohibited, and for this reason some legal scholars argue that the "private facts" tort is unconstitutional in the US. But in many cases the Court has held that false speech is also protected, so truth is not the primary criterion.

In [*Brandenberg vs Ohio* 395 U.S. 444 (1969)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburg_v._Ohio) the "Clear and present danger" test was replaced by a rule that only  speech "directed to inciting or producing imminent lawless action and is likely to incite or produce such action" may be prohibited under the first amendment, and this is now the test for any crime of "incitement". Under this test *Schenck* would hav gone the other way. This test says nothing about the truth of the speech, and a perfectly true statement may nevertheless be incitement if it seeks to arouse lawless action, and is likely to succeed.

*Near vs Minnesota* held that bare truth must be a defense in any prior restraint case (unlike truth published "with good motives and for justifiable ends" which the saturate at issue in *Near* allowed as a defense), but went on to greatly restrict any prior restraint, even if the content was false.

Defamation is really the primary situation in which falsity is a vital  element of the offense, and so truth is a defense.

Falsity is an element of perjury also, and so truth would be an absolute defense there as well. Falsity is also an element of the common-law tort of fraud, and of most statutory versions of fraud, but in some of those a true but misleading statement can still be held fraudulent, so truth is not an absolute defense.

I cannot think of another such legal situation.
**Updatew:**

A comment asked:

> What if I inform all of Joe's neighbours that Joe had been arrested for murder - when I fully know that he was completely exonerated and the real murderer is in jail right now. It's literally the truth, but completely misleading.

In that case the law takes you to have made **by implication** a statement that Joe is currently under suspicion for murder, or perhaps a statement that Joe is actually  guilty of murder. As those statements are false, and apparently knowingly false, they can be the basis of a defamation action. There is a lot of caselaw on defamation by implication, but in general one is taken to have made statements that are clearly implied by the statements one did in fact make.  I don't think this is very different in UK and US law, but I am not sure about the UK. Anyway truth is not a defense here because the implied statement is not true.

Comment: I have since learned the case is based upon a falsehood. Shouting fire in a theater usually results in almost everybody staying put even when there is a fire.

Answer (score 2):

The truth defense regarding shouting "fire" is baked into the statute criminalizing the conduct: see [ORC 2917.31](https://law.justia.com/codes/ohio/2006/orc/jd_291731-9b31.html) for Ohio and analogs in other jurisdictions

> No person shall cause the evacuation of any public place, or otherwise
> cause serious public inconvenience or alarm, by doing any of the
> following:
>
> (1) Initiating or circulating a report or warning of an alleged or
> impending fire, explosion, crime, or other catastrophe, knowing that
> such report or warning is false;

Likewise perjury statutes, false statement / report statutes, criminal fraud statutes etc. where the definition of the crime includes the fact of a statement being false (indeed, knowingly false). It is remotely conceivable that somewhere there is a statute against "inducing panic" which prohibits making true statements that result in public alarm, where truth of statement is taken to be an absolute defense, but I've never seen a version of the law that doesn't include falseness as a definitional element.

Comment: Yeah, ask the Boston Police if it's legal to broadcast dire terror warnings about a "Hoax Device", as they did in the Great Mooninite Invasion of 2007.

Comment: And there are probably variations where the "shouter" actually saw smoke, and "reasonably" believed there to be fire, except that there was no fire.

Comment: Inciting to riot is an offense even if all statements made are true.